# react-slick carousel CSS, "Failed to compile" error

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slick.js, react-slick

I'm having an issue with my react-slick carousel. I'm following official documentation and installation steps but I'm getting this error:

[image]

It seems to be a very common error, and I've tried solution which I've found here on stackoverflow - delete this block of code from `slick-theme.scss`.

```css
    /* Slider */
    
    .slick-list {
        .slick-loading & {
            background: #fff slick-image-url("ajax-loader.gif") center center no-repeat;
        }
    }
    
    /* Icons */
    @if $slick-font-family == "slick" {
        @font-face {
            font-family: "slick";
            src: slick-font-url("slick.eot");
            src: slick-font-url("slick.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), slick-font-url("slick.woff") format("woff"), slick-font-url("slick.ttf") format("truetype"), slick-font-url("slick.svg#slick") format("svg");
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
    }
```

Firstly, it doesn't help, but after 5 minutes of trying to find another solution it magically starts working and now, after 10 minutes of trying to configure it, stylize it and add content to slides, this error fires again.

Does anybody please have solution for this? Or maybe some advice for different React carousel which is not as buggy as this one? Even if it starts working for 10 minutes, some features didn't work, for example, dots, the were no arrows for switching slides, etc.

Thanks for any help.